# Wordpress admin stylesheet

Tags: admin, css, wp-enqueue-style

Is there a way to override the styles in the admin in my theme?

I don't want to touch the admin style sheet if I don't have to.

I just want to make a column bigger in my admin, but also, to do it in a way that doesn't get overridden in a future wordpress update.

Answer (score 26):

Take a look here at the [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) for an example on how to do this very thing.

**Example: Load CSS File on All Admin Pages**

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style(){
    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style');
```

**Example: Target a Specific Admin Page**

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'edit.php' != $hook )
    return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('/myscript.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Comment: Does the css I create "add" to the current admin style? I only need to override 1 style so I don't want to have to skin the entire admin side...

Comment: correct, it adds to the already existing styles

Comment: this worked fine. I'll just add that more modern way to give path to stylesheet is `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook in combination with [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) in a manner similar to this:

```
// you may want to wrap add_action() in a conditional to prevent enqueue on every page
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse44753_admin_enqueue' );

function wpse44753_admin_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpse44753_style',
        'script/location/here.css', // you probably want to use plugins_url() for this
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using "add_editor_style( array|string $stylesheet = 'editor-style.css' )" ?

"The parameter $stylesheet is the name of the stylesheet, relative to the theme root. It also accepts an array of stylesheets. It is optional and defaults to ‘editor-style.css’.

This function automatically adds another stylesheet with -rtl prefix, e.g. editor-style-rtl.css. If that file doesn’t exist, it is removed before adding the stylesheet(s) to TinyMCE. If an array of stylesheets is passed to add_editor_style(), RTL is only added for the first stylesheet."

```
/**
 * Registers an editor stylesheet for the theme.
 */
 if ( ! function_exists( 'ns_admin_custom_css' ) ) : 
 function ns_admin_custom_css() {
    add_editor_style( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin.css' );
 }
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'ns_admin_custom_css' );
 endif;
```