# How to load css file in my menu in wordpress

Tags: menus, wp-enqueue-style

Anyone know how to load css file in my menu in wordpress. use this but it didn't work

```
function wmt_theme_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '3.3.4', 'all' );
 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wmt_theme_style' );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) hook. As you can imagine, you're not the first one to attempt that: [Wordpress admin stylesheet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44753/wordpress-admin-stylesheet)