# animate.style on wp-login.php

Tags: jquery, login, wp-login-form

I am relatively new to WordPress code and would like to enhance my login page with https://animate.style/ or other jQuery code. Do you think there are any security concerns in doing this? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress admin stylesheet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44753/wordpress-admin-stylesheet)

Comment: _Are you asking how to do it? Or are you asking if this is secure?_ Note that the site you llnked to is not a jQuery plugin or javascript, it is pure CSS ( I use it on my own site )

Answer (score 0):

By using the following code in your `functions.php` file, I believe you can achieve the required result.

```
function login_stylesheets() {

    wp_register_style( 'animate_css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'my_login_stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/LINK/TO/YOUR/CSS/FILE.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate_css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_login_stylesheet' );

}
add_action( 'login_head', 'login_stylesheets' );
```

The above `wp_register_style` function is derived from the [WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/). From here it is just a matter of editing the `my_login_stylesheet` CSS file and customising to your hearts content! (Be sure to use [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) for referencing login CSS classes. Also make sure to change `/LINK/TO/YOUR/CSS/FILE.css` to the directory of your actual CSS file.)

I hope that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and thanks for the code. but i was more concerned about security. could jquery on the wp-login.php cause problems, compromise the security of the whole site?

Comment: I believe if you use the correct WordPress functions provided, you should be fine!

Comment: Also, animate.style is simply a CSS file, so jQuery is not a problem here.

Comment: @robinex animate.css has nothing to do with jQuery or javascript, it's pure CSS, it's a stylesheet that adds helper classes for CSS animations